# PHP rand from list

Tags: php, random

What is the best way of doing this ?

```
rand('Helloworld','Hi world');
```

I know this is not working as rand needs a min and max number, but what is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

Comment: I didn't know this function, thanks. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

Something likes that:

```
<?php
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
$array[ mt_rand( 0, count($array) -1 ) ];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) for sure. Example:

```
<?php

$names = array('Neo', 'Morpheus', 'Trinity', 'Cypher', 'Tank');
echo 'Hello ' . $names[array_rand($names)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function rand_of() {
    $_ = func_get_args();
    return $_[rand(0, count($_) - 1)];
}

echo rand_of("foo", "bar", "baz");
```